# isometric embedding of l^2

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

CLAIM: Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-Hilbert space. Then the $\ell^2$ sequence space can be embedded in $H$.

I think it could be true since every Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ and so the map

$\Phi:H\rightarrow \ell^2,x\mapsto<x,x_i>_{i\in I}$ is an isometric isomorphism.

Am I missing something?

Comment: are from UZH? :D

Comment: yesssss I am ^^

Comment: Would you like to tell me who you are? :)

Comment: sure I could ;)

Comment: whats your name then? ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a sequence $x_{i(n)}$ from your orthonormal basis. An embedding is  then $\ell^2 \ni (\alpha_n)_n \mapsto \sum_n \alpha_n x_{i(n)} \in H$. What you write is an ismomorphism
$H\to \ell^2(I)$.

Comment: yes but if I have an isomorphism then I also have an embedding.. does it hold then?

Comment: @sky90 For uncountable $I$ I would not call $\ell^2(I)$ a *sequence space*.

Comment: Could you give me an advice? I don't know how to procede...

Comment: What I wrote in the answer is an (isometric) embedding because $\|\sum_n \alpha_n x_{i(n)}\|_H^2 = \sum_n|\alpha_n|^2 = \|(\alpha_n)_n\|_{\ell^2}$.